# Mezclar dos strings hasta la longitud de la palabra más corta

Tags: python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que solo mezcle los dos strings hasta la longitud de la palabra mas corta

```
def mezclarpalabras2(cad1, cad2):
    if len(cad1) != len(cad2):
        min_cad=min(cad1, cad2, key=len)
        max_cad=max(cad1, cad2, key=len)
    else:
        min_cad=cad1
        max_cad=cad2
    
    result1=""
    result2=""
    for index in range(0, len(min_cad)):
        result1 += min_cad[index] + max_cad[index]
        result2 += max_cad[index] + min_cad[index]
    
    return (result1, result2)
```

Comment: Muy bonita tu tarea, que has intentado?? Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask]. Recuerda que aquí no se hacen tareas/trabajos, se ayuda con problemas en el código que tengas

Answer (score 0):

Se puede calcular la cadena más larga con un `if/else` tradicional, o también usando un ternario.

Entonces tu código quedaría como:

```
def mezclarpalabras(cad1, cad2):
    limit = len(cad1) if len(cad1) <= len(cad2) else len(cad2)
    result1=""
    result2=""
    for index in range(0, limit):
        result1 += cad1[index] + cad2[index]
        result2 += cad2[index] + cad1[index]
    return (result1, result2)
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda pero sigue con el mismo problema. No mezcla los dos strings hasta la longitud de la palabra mas corta. Realmente la funcion deberia funcionar asi:texto_3='aaaaaaaaaa'
texto_4='bbbb'

In: mezclarPalabras(texto_3,texto_4)
Out: ['abab', 'baba']

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es muy difícil, con un simple ciclo `for` especificando el parámetro `step` (paso) es suficiente. En cada iteración agregamos 2 letras y no 1, por tal razón debemos de aumentar el contador en 2, si solo se aumenta en 1 obtendremos una cadena del doble de tamaño que la cadena mas pequeña.

```py
def mezclar_palabras(cad1, cad2):
    mini = len(cad1) if len(cad1) <= len(cad2) else len(cad2)

    cadena = ""
    for i in range(0, mini, 2):
        cadena+= f"{cad1[i]}{cad2[i]}"

    return cadena

print(mezclar_palabras('aaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbb'))
```

Si ejecutamos eso obtendremos:

```
abab
```

Si quieres obtener `baba` deberás de poner la segunda cadena primero, es decir, hacer `f"{cad2[i]}{cad1[i]}"`. Pero seguramente lo que quiere es colocar la primera letra de la cadena más pequeña, en ese caso un `if` basta.

```py
def mezclar_palabras(cad1, cad2):
    if len(cad1) <= len(cad2):
        mini = len(cad1)
    else:
        mini = len(cad2)
        cad1, cad2 = cad2, cad1  
        
    cadena = ""
    for i in range(0, mini, 2):
        cadena+= f"{cad1[i]}{cad2[i]}"

    return cadena
```